# How to receive file attachments from Mailgun in Go

Tags: email, go, mailgun

I'm trying to find out how to receive file attachments for email from mailgun with golang. They provide only python example https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-receiving.html:

```
# Handler for HTTP POST to http://myhost.com/messages for the route defined above
def on_incoming_message(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
         sender    = request.POST.get('sender')
         recipient = request.POST.get('recipient')
         subject   = request.POST.get('subject', '')

         body_plain = request.POST.get('body-plain', '')
         body_without_quotes = request.POST.get('stripped-text', '')
         # note: other MIME headers are also posted here...

         # attachments:
         for key in request.FILES:
             file = request.FILES[key]
             # do something with the file

     # Returned text is ignored but HTTP status code matters:
     # Mailgun wants to see 2xx, otherwise it will make another attempt in 5 minutes
     return HttpResponse('OK')
```

How should I handle this part in Go, or what type this 'files' is?

```
# attachments:
         for key in request.FILES:
             file = request.FILES[key]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have Mailgun send sample requests for callbacks in the routing settings for your domain: https://app.mailgun.com/app/routes. For a quick overview, create a bin on http://bin.mailgun.net and enter that URL.

You will see that the requests for "forward" actions contain multipart/form-data bodies, so you use [http.Request.FormFile](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormFile) to access the attachments:

```
http.HandleFunc("/callback", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // r.FormFile and r.FormValue will call ParseMultipartForm
    // automatically if necessary, but they ignore any errors. For
    // robustness we do it ourselves.
    if err := r.ParseMultipartForm(10 << 20); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
        return
    }

    // The "attachment-count" field reports how many attachments there are.
    n, _ := strconv.Atoi(r.FormValue("attachment-count"))

    // The file fields are then named "attachment-1", "attachment-2", ..., "attachment-n".
    for i := 1; i <= n; i++ {
        fieldName := fmt.Sprintf("attachment-%d", i)
        file, header, err := r.FormFile(fieldName)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
            return
        }

        fmt.Printf("%s (%d bytes)\n", header.Filename, header.Size)

        var _ = file // call file.Read() to read the file contents
    }
})
```

For Mailgun's test payload the output will be:

```
crabby.gif (2785 bytes)
attached_файл.txt (32 bytes)
```

Comment: Got `http: multipart handled by ParseMultipartForm` in this line:
`mr, err := r.MultipartReader()`

Comment: I'm using gin-gonic and it's actually `mr, err := c.Request.MultipartReader()` but `c.Request` is `*http.Request` anyway.

Comment: I'm not familiar with gin, but judging from the code you can just call [`c.MultipartForm()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.MultipartForm). I forgot about Request.ParseMultipartForm. That's actually simpler and will update the answer.

Comment: Thank you for help, `c.MultipartForm()` did it.

Comment: Gin also has c.FormFile(), by the way. If you know how many attachments to expect, that may be simpler for you. See updated answer.